# How to map DeviceID to human readable parameters like client name?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to disable device or find logs for particular client. How could I find out what `deviceID` associated with particular client?

I use Android native and iOS native

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "particular client". A customer that you know exactly who it is? An employee?

Comment: It's a customer. I know first and last name of the person. Could I find all deviceIDs associated with this person?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what kind of client-side technology you are using, but assuming hybrid, MFP provides client-side APIs for getting hold of a device ID, e.g. [`getID()` in the JavaScript API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.1.0%2F10-0-0-1-9&lang=en).

Comment: I use native Android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

With device access management feature,  you can see device Id mapped to a user Id in the operations console Devices tab. Refer to
 https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_access_mgmt.html